# Error while trying to execute .robot file using robot.run

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to execute **Run_Keyword.robot** made with **RIDE** file which is in directory **'Robot'** from python interpreter and getting following error. I am able to run this .py file from **cmd** without any error and it gives expected results.
What can be the reason for this. I am a newbie to Robot Framework. Please help with this.

```
from robot import run
run(suite = 'Robot')
```

The Error I am getting is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uvijayac\Desktop\Robot\rf.py", line 27, in <module>
    run_tests()
  File "C:\Users\uvijayac\Desktop\Robot\rf.py", line 23, in run_tests
    report=report_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\run.py", line 471, in run
    return RobotFramework().execute(*datasources, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py", line 83, in execute
    return self._execute(list(arguments), options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self._report_error(unicode(err), help=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py", line 110, in _report_error
    self._logger.error(message)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\loggerhelper.py", line 59, in error
    self.write(msg, 'ERROR')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\loggerhelper.py", line 62, in write
    self.message(Message(message, level, html))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\logger.py", line 109, in message
    logger.message(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\monitor.py", line 66, in message
    self._writer.error(msg.message, msg.level, clear=self._running_test)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\monitor.py", line 142, in error
    self._highlight('[ ', level, ' ] ' + message, error=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\monitor.py", line 158, in _highlight
    self._write(before, newline=False, error=error)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\monitor.py", line 154, in _write
    stream.flush()
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
>>>
```

Comment: The error is related with some file path. You are running in python console, are you sure that the robot file is in same directory? What if you run  cd into `C:\Users\uvijayac\Desktop\Robot\` and run directly `python .\rf.py`?
Did you create the directory `robotx_test_result`?

Comment: I changed suite to directory name. 
Now I am able to run rf.py from cmd as "python rf.py" and it gives expected result.
Still the same error when running from Python interpreter.